# TinyMCE doesn't work correctly in the Media Modal Window

Tags: tinymce

I need to add TinyMCE to descriptions of images. For it, I'm using this code in my functions.php:

```
function add_tiny_mce_hook() {      
if (function_exists('wp_tiny_mce')){ 
    wp_tiny_mce(false, 
        array(
            'remove_linebreaks' => false, 
            'mode'              => 'textareas', 
            'editor_selector'   => 'my-tinymce-class')
        );
}}
function alternate_tiny_mce_method($fields, $post) {
if (isset($fields['post_content'])) {
    $value = $fields['post_content']['value'];
    $label = $fields['post_content']['label'];
    $name = 'post_content';
    $fields[$name] = array(
        'label' => $label,
        'input' => 'html',
        'html' => '<textarea name="attachments['.$post->ID.']['.$name.']" id="'.$name.'-'.$post->ID.'" class="my-tinymce-class">'.nl2br($value).'</textarea>'
    );
}
return $fields;}
add_action('admin_head', 'add_tiny_mce_hook');
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'alternate_tiny_mce_method', 10, 2);
```

On the Edit Media page works fine (wp-admin/media.php?attachment_id=XXX&action=edit). But, I have a problem after opening "Add an Image" modal window, and switching to the "Gallery" tab, from "Edit Post". I can't add a link via TinyMCE editor. Every time I click Add Link from the pop-up modal nothing happens.

I see the problem in gallery.js (gallery.dev.js; wp-admin/js/gallery.js; WordPress loads this JS).
There are 3 lines that do me the trouble:
....
tinymce = w.tinymce;
tinyMCE = w.tinyMCE;
t.editor = tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor;
....

When I drop "tinymce = w.tinymce;" and "tinyMCE = w.tinyMCE;" and replace "tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor;" with "w.tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor" - works fine. 
But, I don't want to do a core mod to WordPress

My WordPress version is 3.2.1

Any help, please.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same "problem" just two days ago. Finally it worked somehow but wasn't reliable at all. Switching editors just didn't work occasionally and as said, wasn't a reliable solution.

The only reason to use tinyMCE here was the ability to add links to attachments. I took an other route and came to this solution:

http://www.screenr.com/xYas

I've done this for somebody else, so this is just a early demo, quick & dirty.
The final script is a bit prettier. If you're interested, please send a short mail to kai@[->myusername<-].de or find me at twitter @ungestaltbar

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing priority for the [attachment_fields_to_edit](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Database_Reads)  filter:

```
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'alternate_tiny_mce_method', 15, 2);
```

Comment: An explanation would be useful.